# Windows 10: Missing taskbar shortcuts on startup

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts, windows-10-v1703, bitdefender

As my title suggests, I am missing all my taskbar shortcuts on startup of Windows 10. I have fount my own workaround for now: When I pin/unpin something from the taskbar the rest of the pinned shortcuts show up.

OS:

Windows 10 Pro - Version: 1703 - OS Build: 15063.13

Since this is my first question here, and I can't post multiple links, I've gathered my screenshots of the error and the workaround here:

[image: screenshots]

Have any of you experienced this? And possibly have a better solution for it than my current workaround..?

Comment: Are you in Tablet Mode? Have you installed Bitdefender Anti-Ransomware?

Comment: No, I am in Desktop mode, and yes, Bitdefender's Ransomware Protection is running.

Comment: Go to this folder `"%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"`, how many shortcuts do you see? Also see the `Favorites` registry value in `"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband"`, do you see all the shortcuts path?

Comment: When looking in the folder I saw all but two shortcuts - Chrome and Mail. I tried unpinning those two and rebooting, but no change...

How do you read the value from the registry? All i see is the hex value...

Comment: Try disabling Bitdefender Anti-Ransomware - it had a problem in this domain (I don't know if that problem is fixed by now).

Comment: @harrymc Yep. That did it! I've tinkered with it and it seems to be an issue with the "Protect at boot" option... Turning that off solved the issue. Thank you! :D (If you wanna write up an answer I'll mark it as correct)

Comment: Found this forum post: https://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?/topic/74118-sent2devel-protection-at-boot/

If you remove Desktop from protected folders it will leave the taskbar alone, even with "Protection at boot" on.

Comment: @DennisJensen: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitdefender Anti-Ransomware is known for causing problems with the taskbar.

The first report of this problem seems to date from January 2016 :
[Windows 10 Quick Launch Icons Disappear Upon Reboot](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/601182/windows-10-quick-launch-icons-disappear-upon-reboot/#entry3921293).

The accepted workaround that was found says:

> This "disappearing" task bar icon issue only happens when the
>   "Desktop" folder is being protected by the Bitdefender 2016
>   Anti-Ransomware module.  If you remove the "Desktop" folder from the
>   list of protected folders, the problem is resolved.

For more information see the Bitdefender article
[How to add exclusions (exceptions) in Bitdefender 2016](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-add-exclusions-(exceptions)-in-bitdefender-2016-1467.html).

The poster has also found that turning off the "Protect at boot" option
also solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this same issue for a while (Windows 10 pro 20H2, build 19042.1165)

and this seemed to fix it 'most' of the time.

Control Panel > Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do >
then uncheck "Turn on fast startup".

Turning this off for whatever reason seemed to fix this issue most of the time.